# While using Screen Sharing, a double click to the remote Mac acts like a single click

Tags: imac, mouse, mac-mini, screen-sharing, click

I'm using Apple's Screen Sharing to control a headless Mac mini from an iMac. Things mostly work, except when I try to double click anything on the Mac mini, it acts like a single click.

I've tried adjusting double click speed using System Preferences on both the Mac mini and the iMac with no success. I've tried setting the sender double click to very fast while the receiver is set to very slow, and then clicking at various speeds. No combination seems to work.

As a test, I plugged a mouse into the Mac mini and I can double click items normally.

Any suggestions on how to make double clicking work?

Comment: Possibility that it’s a lag issue - you adjusted double-click speed on the Mini, but have you tried double-clicking more slowly? To rapid clicks may possibly be misinterpreted as a single click if there’s lag in the connection.

Comment: That's very unlikely a lag issue. I have the exactly the same problem on a MacBook (Running OSX 10.8.5) connecting to a macOS 10.5.4 host. But on another MacBook running OSX 10.9.5 it worked seamlessly. I assume that could be a compatibility issue.

Comment: In karabiner eventviewer, I find it recognises every click, but click_count doesn't add up. Quite interesting, I have no clues at all...

Comment: To our worse disappointments, alternative pointer behaviour in accessibility preferences doesn’t work either, macOS handles remote inputs in a really special way. (It’s a 10.15.4 host, I had a typo )